# PHP session containing Facebook access token inconsistent on web server but fine on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, session

I have uploaded my site to a web server and the access token session data is inconsistent when passing data back to the index page. All works fine when tested on localhost.

I have made the relevant changes needed to re-directs etc.

The session is created with the following code:

```
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,picture,first_name,last_name,email,age_range,gender', $accessToken);
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
```

I am then calling the session data for sign in/out links on the index page using the following script:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){Log In script}
else{
Log Out script}?>
```

Both Log in and Log out work occasionally, however majority of the time not.

Answer (score 0):

PHP needed to be upgraded with host.